# How to get complete list of UDP connections made by each application using adb or appium

Tags: android, tcp, udp, adb, appium-android

I am trying to get network connections and their five-tuples made by each application in android.

Currently I'm using the following commands to get five-tuples and applications PID:
TCP connections: **adb shell cat /proc/net/tcp**
UDP connections: **adb shell cat /proc/net/udp**

for TCP it works fine, but for UDP it doesn't show destination's IP and port and its list is not complete.

further information: I have used both emulator and real device. Also I used both **appium** and **adb** command line, but all of them have this problem.